# How do I logout from deepstream.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deepstream.io

I can close the connection with `ds.close()` but as soon as I run `ds.login()` I get logged in as the same user, regardless of the credentials provided.

```
ds.login({user: 'admin', pass: 'admin'})
// AUTH_SUCCESSFUL | admin

ds.close()
// CLIENT_DISCONNECTED | admin

ds.login({})
// INCOMING_CONNECTION | from http://localhost:3000/ (127.0.0.1) via engine.io
// AUTH_SUCCESSFUL | admin
```

<strike>Even if I create a new `deepstream` client instance before logging in again, the user does not change.</strike>

Comment: You should consider filing a bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, closing the connection, and creating a new instance seems to do the trick. I'll go with this monkey patch for now...

```
import deepstreamClient from 'deepstream.io-client-js'

const createClient = () => deepstreamClient('localhost:6020')

window.ds = createClient()

ds.logout = () => {
  ds.close()
  window.ds = createClient()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ds.login` again is meant to override the auth parameters with what is passed in. Created an issue to test this out and see we can replicate it / see if there is a bug somewhere.

Line it overrides at can be seen [here](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io-client-js/blob/master/src/message/connection.js#L72)

Issue raised [here](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io-client-js/issues/88)